# MyBatis "or" criteria

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to create a query with MyBatis, which will produce something like:

```
SELECT first_field, second_filed, third_field
WHERE first_field > 1 AND (second_field > 0 OR third_field < 0)
```

How could I construct that with Criteria objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this would be to [extend the generated Example classes](http://mybatis.github.io/generator/generatedobjects/extendingExampleClass.html):

> The generated "example" class includes a nested inner class where the actual functionality of the predicates exists. This inner class is always named GeneratedCriteria.
>
> MBG also generates an inner class named Criteria which extends GeneratedCriteria and which you may use for adding your own functions to the example classes. **The Criteria class will not be deleted** by the Eclipse Java code merger, so you may add to it without fear of losing your changes upon regeneration.

So basically,generate your example class, and add your custom criteria.

```
    public Criteria multiColumnOrClause(String value1, String value2) {
        addCriterion("value1 = " + value1 + " OR value2 = " + value2);
        return this;
    }
```

If you reuse it often, and don't want to do this for all your mappers, you can also extract the logic in a "plugin", although the documentation is a bit lacking on this, there's only one example :

[org.mybatis.generator.plugins.CaseInsensitiveLikePlugin](http://mybatis.github.io/generator/cobertura/org.mybatis.generator.plugins.CaseInsensitiveLikePlugin.html)

Comment: Note: you need add parenthesys too to the multi-column-or-clause.

Comment: There may be a risk of SQL injection？

Comment: Technically yes, the code here is just a dummy example. In a real world scenario 1/ you might not want to handle sanitization at the query building level, it should done waaaay earlier, when handling user input, and 2/ you could use more precise types (not strings)

Answer (score 13):

Since `a AND (b OR c)` is the same as `(a AND b) or (a AND c)`

```
TestTableExample example = new TestTableExample();
example.createCriteria()
  .andField1GreaterThan(1)
  .andField2GreaterThan(0);
example.or(example.createCriteria()
  .andField1GreaterThan(1)
  .andField3LessThan(0));
```

then sit back and let the SQL optimizer figure it out.

Comment: Amazing solution - would the performance be the same?

Comment: @young-ceo depends on the SQL engine, I would think any decent engine would have identical performance between `a AND (b OR c)` and `(a AND b) or (a AND c)`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand now, there is no possibility to do that with standard generated mapper.